# How to prevent strange edits and why users approve it?

Tags: discussion, editing

Today I found some edits which is looking very strange made by the user https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/83709/deadly :

https://magento.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/170024
https://magento.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/170025

How to deal with that "improvements" and why some users approved it? Could someone stop them?

Comment: He is still doing same edits https://magento.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/170312

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Siarhey Uchukhlebau

thanks for your information, we will look into it.

Deadly's edits does not improvement content. We will contact him.

Comment: Could you please contact Munesh one more time? :)